# Example of commutative ring with two nonzero prime ideals $P,Q$ such that $P\subsetneq Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've tried the obvious examples with $\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm blanking.

Is there an elementary example that works?

Comment: Why is there a close vote? The fact that this question is easy to answer from an experienced algebraist does not make it a bad question. Actually if one starts to learn about rings, one encounters mostly one-dimensional domains ($\mathbb Z, K[X]$) and zero-dimensional (fields, $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$) rings. These examples have in common that there are no proper inclusions between non-zero prime ideals. So I would say the question is pretty legit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classic examples would be $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $P=(x)$ and $Q=(2,x)$, and also $k[x,y]$ with $P=(x)$ and $Q=(x,y)$ for any field $k$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For any integral domain $R$ with nonzero prime ideal $P$, the ring $R\times R$ has the prime ideals $R\times P$ and $R\times\{0\}$.

In particular you could use $\mathbb Z$. These are distinct from Zev's examples since these are never domains.

Comment: +1 ; I like this, because this is an one-dimensional example and the construction does not leave the 'one-dimensional world', i.e. it is not constructed as a quotient of something higher-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that $\Bbb Z$ has the property that *all nonzero prime ideals are maximal*.

There are tons of examples of what you're looking for. For instance, look at the prime ideal $\mathfrak p=(y-x^2)\subset k[x,y]$. Imagine this prime ideal representing the curve $y=x^2$ in the plane. Then, any point on this curve corresponds to a maximal (prime) ideal containing $\mathfrak p$. For instance, the point $(1,1)$ is on the curve $y=x^2$, and you can check $(y-x^2)\subset (x-1,y-1)$.